# I'm getting the undefined method `user_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, factory-bot

This passes:

```
describe "log page" do
#let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
#let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:status_update, user: user ) }
#let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:status_update, user: user ) }

before { visit user_path(user) }

#it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.email) }
#it { should have_selector('title', text: user.email) }

#describe "logs" do
#  it { should have_content(m1.weight) }
#  it { should have_content(m2.weight) }
#  it { should have_content(user.status_updates.count) }
#end
end
```

When I uncomment everything else, it fails.

why does this happen?! I'v been pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you're missing a subject. Try adding:

```
subject { page }
```

before the `it` blocks.

Comment: The parent block has a subject already. It's when I add the Factory Girl parts that it fails. Also, I'm following this tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#sec-the_basic_model , and I'm at 10.19 at the moment. 
 
I'm not making the tutorial but just following along with it.

Comment: Hmm... it must be something in your factory definition. Can you post the relevant factory code?

Comment: Here's someone with the same error, caused by a problem in the factory definition: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/399 so I suspect it's something there.

Comment: Also another question: are you using this factory anywhere else in your specs? If so, is it working there?

Comment: I figured the problem out. I was posting this code in the wrong spec file. :D I was posting it in user_spec.rb instead of user_pages_spec.rb so that's why the subject wasn't working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, that's tricky to debug! You have to take a step back sometimes, the problem is often outside of the code you're actually testing.